# Entity framework Include - Can we have it condition based .Include(p => includeFiles == true ? p.FileMasters : null)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to have Include work based on function parameter as used in code below. By going throug [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation for Include, looks like it's not possible.

```
public static Response<Person> GetById(int id, bool includeAddress = false
    , bool includeFiles = false
    , bool includeTags = false)
{
    var output = new Response<Person>();

    using (var dbContext = new SmartDataContext())
    {
        dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        output.Entity = dbContext.EntityMasters.OfType<Person>()
            .Include(p => includeFiles == true ? p.FileMasters : null)
            .Include(p => includeAddress == true ? p.Addresses : null)
            .Include(p => includeTags == true ? p.Tags : null)
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.EntityId == id);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Is there any trick to handle it directly or I have to build expression instead. I am not sure even how would I build an expression for this rather checking in dbContext. **I am thinking if I can build expression before entering dbContext** scope.

What I am looking for is to have all the conditions resolved before jumping into `USING` statement. In example below I creating an expression and using it inside `USING`

```
public static Response<IEnumerable<ConfigurationType>> GetByAttributeType(int attributeType)
{
    Response<IEnumerable<ConfigurationType>> output = new Response<IEnumerable<ConfigurationType>>();

    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ConfigurationType, bool>> expressions=null;
    switch (attributeType)
    {
        case 1:
            expressions = a => a.IsItemAttribute == true;
            break;
        case 2:
            expressions = a => a.IsReadPointAttribute == true;
            break;
        default:
            expressions = a => a.IsPersonAttribute == true;
            break;
    }


    using (var context = new SmartDataContext())
    {
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        output.Entity = context.ConfigurationTypes.Where(expressions).ToList();              
    }

    return output;
}
```

Similarly what I am expecting is something like this. This sounds weird, just trying to overthink may be if there is a way to resolve p somehow.

```
IQueryable<Person> query = includeFiles?Include(p=>p.Files):null; //p is undefined
query.Append(includeTags?Include(p=>p.Tags):null);
```

I am not sure if it's possible or not. If not, please help me understand the reason.

Comment: But in your sample code you're inside the scope of the DbContext. The condition you've placed on it doesn't even make sense, the DbContext is what knows about your entities. What you're asking is impossible.

Comment: Isn't it possible with an help of `expression tree` as well?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta I think you need to further elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish.  The typical pattern for entity framework is that you create a context instance and then construct your query starting from a context member (e.g. `EntityMasters` in your case).  The pieces of your query can be defined elsewhere, or built using expression trees, but you still start with your context because it is the query provider.

Comment: Also you should change the title of your question if it has less to do with conditionally applying `Include` and more to do with building queries outside of the scope of an entity context.

Comment: No. You can't manipulate an object before you create it. The query is built off of the collections that the DbContext exposes. Before you enter the `using`, there is no object to operate on.

Comment: Your first example is possible because you're defining an expression that is an input to a linq method.  The expression has no dependencies on the context so it could be created anywhere.  Your second example is not possible because the `Include` method requires the source query as input, and the source query comes from the context, so it is not available until you're inside your `using` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your query up piece by piece, calling `Include` conditionally.  If you want to perform this work using logic outside of the using statement (and / or outside of the method), you could pass a type that encapsulates the logic for applying the necessary `Include` statements.

For example:

```
public static Response<Person> GetById(int id, IIncludeConfiguration<Person> includeConfiguration = null)
{
    var output = new Response<Person>();

    using (var dbContext = new SmartDataContext())
    {
        dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var query = dbContext.EntityMasters.OfType<Person>();

        if(includeConfiguration != null)
        {
            query = includeConfiguration.ApplyIncludes(query);
        }

        output.Entity = query.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EntityId == id);
    }

    return output;
}

public interface IIncludeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : class;
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyIncludes(IQueryable<TEntity> query)
}

public class PersonIncludeConfiguration : IIncludeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public bool IncludeFiles {get;set;}
    public bool IncludeAddresses {get;set;}
    ....


    public IQueryable<Person> ApplyIncludes(IQueryable<Person> query)
    {
        if(IncludeFiles) query = query.Include(x => x.FileMasters);
        if(IncludeAddresses) query = query.Include(x => x.Addresses);
        ....
        return query;
    }

GetById(1234, new PersonIncludeConfiguration{IncludeFiles = true});
```

Comment: This can only be done within `USING context`. I am wondering if its possible before using context.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta Please see my edits for an example of how to move this configuration outside of the context.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking. But it's a good suggestion. Updating my question

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way but you can always build up the `IQuerable` on your own. Something like:

```
var queryable = dbContext.EntityMasters.OfType<Person>();
if (includeFiles)
{
    queryable = queryable.Include(p => p.FileMasters);
}
```

Comment: This can only be done within `USING context`. I am wondering if its possible before using context.